# Record or Compare mysql data before and after operation -reverse engineering

Tags: php, mysql, reverse-engineering

My problem is I'm using a HUGE web application (a school system), with no documentation for the internal logic. I need to make a bulk update of a particular value, but I don't know what tables in the MySQL database contain the relevant data to update. The app it's self runs from php. Is there an easy way to compare the database before I do an operation and after I do it so I can see what tables are effected? I tried using a diff comparing tool on the dumped sql before and after, but the database is so huge it's really impractical to use, wondering if there is something better or if I can just configure php somehow to log any mysql operations from whatever file happens to trigger them.

Comment: Find the web page that normally updates the the information you want to update, find that place in the code. There you should find the table that is being updated.

Comment: No sorry it's a lot more complex than that.

Comment: There is nothing so complex that one cannot find the code through the url else the browser would never be able to get to a particular block of code to execute. There will always be some sort of routing mechanism that points to particular code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run the performance tool from the mysql workbench and look at the performance reports/statement analysis. This will work if you pick a time when the system is not being used and then run some function in the web that updates the tables with the values you need to change. Look at the performance table before and after you run your experiment and look for those sql statements which show use. It's not perfect, but this will at least help you begin to hone in on the data you're looking for. The big 'gotcha' here is if the value you want to change is dynamically derived during the query process. Then you'll have to understand how the derivation works and the source columns. But, again, this will give you a brute-force starting place.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I want to do, unfortunatly it is telling me I don't have a new enough version of MySql server to run the performance tool.